C# ClearScript V8ScriptEngine - How to add a static function to the engine
I want to ask if somebody of you know, how i can add a static function to the V8ScriptEngine instance? I'm switching from Jint and don't know how this works with V8.
In Jint i passed a function name and a delegate and it works.
_engine.SetValue(sfa.Name, Delegate.CreateDelegate(getType(types.ToArray()), method));
In V8 is no equivalent for this.
In V8 are only functions to add a specific type or an object.

Suppose you have a class with a static method:
public static class Functions {
    public static void PrintNumber(int n) => Console.WriteLine("The number is {0}.", n);
}

You can expose the method like this:
_engine.AddHostObject("printNumber", new Action<int>(Functions.PrintNumber));

And now JavaScript code can call the method:
_engine.Execute("printNumber(25)");


Ahh, okay I can do that, then it will work. Thank you!
